# Swapping slots on Azure Linux web app slow

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines

I have set up a deployment pipeline in Azure DevOps which deploys a .NET 5 web api to a Azure Linux web app deployment slot. After the deployment is done, it swaps the deployment slot with the production slot.

The swap works as it should, but it's rather slow - about 5 minutes for the swap. It seems that the warmup is fast, but it's the swap that takes up all the time.

My pipeline yaml tasks looks like this:

```
- task: AzureWebApp@1
  displayName: "Deploy My webapp"
  inputs:
     azureSubscription: <azureSubscriptionName>
     appType: 'webAppLinux'        
     deployToSlotOrASE: true           
     appName: 'my-web-app'                    
     slotName: 'my-web-app-slot'
     package: '$(PIPELINE.WORKSPACE)/MyWebApp/MyWebApp.zip'

 - task: AzureAppServiceManage@0
   inputs:
     azureSubscription: <AzureSubscriptionName>
     Action: 'Swap Slots'
     WebAppName: 'my-web-app'
     ResourceGroupName: 'MyResourceGroup'
     SourceSlot: 'my-web-app-slot'
```

Looking at the logs of the pipeline when performing the `Swap Slots` task, the following to "tasks" are performed:

1. `Warming-up slots`
2. `Swapping App service 'my-web-app' slots - 'my-web-app-slot' and 'production'`

`Warming-up slots` is *almost* instant. It performs a `GET` request three times where the third request returns `App Service status Code: '302'. Status Message: 'Found'` indicating that the slot has indeed started/is warmed up.

`Swapping App service 'my-web-app' slots - 'my-web-app-slot' and 'production'` is where all the time is used. I starts by sending a `POST` request to the URL: `https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/mysubscription/resouceGroups/myresourcegroup/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/my-web-app/slots/my-web-app-slot/slotsswap?api-version=2016-08-01`

After the `POST` it starts performing `GET` requests to the URL: `https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/mysubscription/resouceGroups/myresourcegroup/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/my-web-app/slots/my-web-app-slot/operationresults/some-guid?api-version=2016-08-01 ==> undefined` which returns status code `202`

After 4 - 5 minutes of getting `202` from the above GET request, it finally receives a `200` http response and the swap is done.

Question is: what exactly is happening during the swap where the GET request keeps getting back a 202 http status code? And: is there any way that I can speed up that process?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Could you please refer this [blog](https://ruslany.net/2017/11/most-common-deployment-slot-swap-failures-and-how-to-fix-them/)

Comment: Hi @bomortensen, Are you still facing the issue ?

Comment: @DelliganeshS-MT I am, yes :-) Thanks for the link, i've read the blog post, but I think the swap times we see are more or less what's to be expected. I think it all comes down to how we structure our deployment pipelines: it just takes time to deploy and swap up to ten web apps in a single pipeline.

Comment: query @bomortensen : you can also do a slot swap 'manually', e.g. in the azure portal. Do you get the same problem with it being slow if you try it that way?

Comment: We observed that the swap time is directly proportional to the number of instances: the higher the scale-out, the slower the swap. They have to physically swap the green physical nodes into the blue ones, but I had expected the time to stay constant, i.e. that they adopted a rolling-based swap, which doesn't seem like the case (or maybe it is but there is some extra overload etc). Not very nice, and it starts to cause painfully long runtimes in our CI/CD pipelines. I'll keep looking.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @  [dixitarora-msft](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11017035/dixitarora-msft), You need to swap based on status code by adding the `WEBSITE_SWAP_WARMUP_PING_PATH` & `WEBSITE_SWAP_WARMUP_PING_STATUSES` in app settings

During the **swap** operation the site in the ***staging slot*** is warmed up by making an `HTTP` request to its root directory. Refer here [How to warm up Azure Web App during deployment slots swap](https://ruslany.net/2015/09/how-to-warm-up-azure-web-app-during-deployment-slots-swap/).

By default, **swap proceed** once the site responds with any `status code`. **Swap not proceed** if the application `fails to warm up` then you can configure it by using below app settings:

**WEBSITE_SWAP_WARMUP_PING_PATH**: The path to make the warm up request to. Set this to a URL path that begins with a slash as the value. For example, “/warmup.php”. The default value is /.

**WEBSITE_SWAP_WARMUP_PING_STATUSES**: Expected HTTP response codes for the warm-up operation. Set this to a comma-separated list of HTTP status codes. For example: “200,202” . If the returned status code is not in the list, the swap operation will not complete. By default, all response codes are valid.

Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58914514/best-practice-for-minimizing-downtime-when-deploying-azure-web-apps)

Comment: Thank you for this answer, as it helps me clarify the overall optimization strategy of the swap, allowing us to 'fail fast' in case the warmup doesn't go as expected. At the same time, this does not address the inherent issue: swapping slots is slow.