# How to achieve zero downtime deployment to Azure web app with database schema updates?

Tags: azure, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I want to implement zero downtime deployment for my .NET application with an Azure SQL database in Azure. I did some research and I found the Slots feature within Azure App service. I could use that, but how can I achieve a zero downtime when I also have a database schema update?

What should be the right strategy, what are the best practices?
Is there also something like slot feature for Azure (sql) databases?
I also couldn't find any article about this topic.

Any idea's/articles?

Comment: I believe that it's impossible to attain true zero-downtime when you have database schema updates, unless you somehow setup a replica of your sql database and use `slot-settings` to point your different `app service slots` to different versions of your database.

Comment: You can try researching the blue/green deployments to see if that meets your use case. You may need to change the way you/your company manages schema changes to adapt to the new process however.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you akseli and Scott Richards for your comments.

Yes, One way is to configure **Azure Web app slots** and **`Staging and Production Slot`**. Perform your *database schema  change* in the *staging slot* and then perform SWAP operation to publish the *staging slot* changes to *Production slot*. And **to reduce downtime utilize** **`Local cache`** **settings** in your **`Production slot`**.

**Local cache** settings **[reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-local-cache#best-practices-for-using-app-service-local-cache)**:-

```
WEBSITE_LOCAL_CACHE_OPTION: Always
WEBSITE_LOCAL_CACHE_SIZEINMB:1
```

[image]

Refer this [**MS Document**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-local-cache#best-practices-for-using-app-service-local-cache) on enabling Local cache setting and FAQ's

- Configure the Production slot by adding the sticky app setting **`WEBSITE_LOCAL_CACHE_OPTION`** with the value Always. If you are using **`WEBSITE_LOCAL_CACHE_SIZEINMB`**, ensure to include it as a sticky setting for the Production slot as well.
- Create a Staging slot and deploy your application to it. Typically, Local Cache is not enabled for the Staging slot to facilitate a smooth build-deploy-test cycle for staging, without utilizing Local Cache benefits.
- Conduct testing on your site using the Staging slot. Once satisfied with the testing results, initiate a swap operation between the Staging and Production slots.
- Sticky settings, which include the name and association with a slot, ensure that the Staging slot inherits the Local Cache app settings during the swap. Consequently, the newly swapped Production slot will run with the local cache activated after a few minutes, as part of the slot warm-up process post-swap. Following the completion of the slot swap, your Production slot will be operational with the local cache in effect.

Deployed the Database schema changed Web app to the Staging slot:-

[image]

***Swap the changes*** from ***Staging to Production Slot.*** If your Production slot shows the previous content even after the Swap make sure this setting is present-

```
WEBSITE_DISABLE_SCM_SEPARATION=true
```

[image]

***Reference:-***

[Best practice for minimizing downtime when deploying Azure Web Apps - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58914514/best-practice-for-minimizing-downtime-when-deploying-azure-web-apps)